How to know layer name from anyone of files map.dbf map.prj map.shp map.shx using go
I am working on the project where we are giving the user to upload GIS layers and it should not be duplicate. what I got to know that user can upload same file multiple time just rename these file (map.dbf  map.prj  map.shp  map.shx).
So I want to know,  there is any way that I can know the layer name by extracting the data from any one of file.
I tried to extract the data from .shp file but I got only attribute not actual layer name.
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/jonas-p/go-shp"
)

func main() {
    // Create a log file
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("shapefile.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
    }
    defer logFile.Close()

    // Set the output of the logger to the log file
    log.SetOutput(logFile)

    // Open a shapefile for reading
    shapeReader, err := shp.Open("map.shp")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer shapeReader.Close()

    // Loop through all features in the shapefile
    for i := 0; shapeReader.Next(); i++ {
        // Print all fields for each feature
        for k, f := range shapeReader.Fields() {
            val := shapeReader.ReadAttribute(i, k)
            log.Printf("%v: %v\n", f, val)
        }
    }
}


ShapeFiles don't have a name other than the name of the file. I suspect that you need to keep track of layer names and add a new suffix to the layer name if they upload the file a second time.
To be honest, you'll face the same issue no matter what data format you use as users often add a table twice.

You are right @Ian there is no provision to store layer name, shape file only containing the information about the layers data like cordinates values.

Hey @Ian, Could you tell me Can one (.shp) Shape File Containing multiple layers?

Layers are usually distinct from data sources being considered a pairing of data and style for rendering

.shp and .dbf files only contains coordinates; they do not contain actual file name. So to avoid duplication of data, we can go with hashing the file content. We can generate a unique identifier that we can compare with other files to determine if they are identical or not. It helps to avoid duplication of data, even if file names are different.
